# Model does not bind from _Footer.cshtml partial view in _Layout.cshtml page in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I want to implement a newsletter subscription function in the footer of my webpage.

The subscription widged must be visible on all pages. For this reason I've integrated it as a partial view in my _Layout.

The `_Layout.cshtml` file is:

```
<body id="top-header">

    <!-- preloader start -->
    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="spin"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- preloader end -->
    <!-- Header Start -->
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Header")
    <!-- Header Close -->

    @RenderBody()

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <partial name="_Footer" model="new SubscribeNewsletterPageModel()" />
    <!-- Footer Close -->
    <!--  Page Scroll to Top  -->
    <a class="scroll-to-top js-scroll-trigger" href="#top-header">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
    <!--  Page Scroll to Top  -->

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <!-- Main Script -->
    <script src="~/js/script.min.js"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    
</body>
```

I have created a `SubscribeNewsletterPageModel.cs` class that contains the model I want to use to post the email address of the subscriber:

```
public class SubscribeNewsletterPageModel : PageModel
{
    

    [BindProperty]
    public Newsletter newsletter { get; set; }


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubscribeNewsletter()
    {

        TempData["returnurl"] = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
        var apiKey = "xxxxx";
        string bearer = "Bearer " + apiKey;
        string newsletterForJSON = newsletter.EMail;

        // queryParams added only for testing
        // in production newsletterForJSON must be used
        string queryParams = @"{
                                  'contacts': [
                                    {
                                      'email': 'firstname.lastname@gmail.com',
                                    }
                                  ]
                                  }";

        JObject queryParamsJSON = JObject.Parse(queryParams);

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", bearer);
        request.AddParameter("application/json", queryParamsJSON, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        var error = response.Content;

        return Redirect(TempData["returnurl"].ToString());

    }

}
```

On my `_Footer.cshtml`, which is a Razor View, I start with my model:

```
@model SubscribeNewsletterPageModel
```

Then I have my form:

```
<form asp-page-handler="SubscribeNewsletter" method="post">
<div class="position-relative">
    <input asp-for="@Model.newsletter.EMail" class="form-control border-0 text-white newsletter-form" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" placeholder="Geben Sie Ihre E-Mail ein">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-subscribe">Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

For my Index Razor Page I've inherited from `SubscribeNewsletterPageModel`

```
public class IndexModel : SubscribeNewsletterPageModel
```

If I start debugging (F5) and set a breakpoint in my `OnPostSubscribeNewsletter` method, I see that my bound property is EMPTY!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I start debugging (F5) and set a breakpoint in my
> OnPostSubscribeNewsletter method, I see that my bound property is
> EMPTY!

Do you mean the Email not bind successfully?

In your _Footer.cshtml , you can try to change the ***name="newsletter"*** into  ***name="newsletter.Email"***
Change the code below

```
<input asp-for="@Model.newsletter.EMail" class="form-control border-0 text-white newsletter-form" id="newsletter" name="newsletter" placeholder="Geben Sie Ihre E-Mail ein">
```

Into

```
<input asp-for="@Model.newsletter.EMail" class="form-control border-0 text-white newsletter-form" id="newsletter" name="newsletter.Email" placeholder="Geben Sie Ihre E-Mail ein">
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Qing Guo, yes you are right. I've also seen that, havig set `asp-for="@Model.newsletter.EMail"` it is not really necessary to specify `name="newsletter.Email"`. The Tag-Helper `asp-for` is already responsible for the binding. In my code, putting `name="newsletter"` was generating the problem and some kind of conflict with the Tag-Helper. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi Code4Fun, I am glad that my answer can help you a little bit. Thank you for sharing your accurate solution.